# PHP: Laravel or Fuel PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, fuelphp

We are currently trying to define the PHP framework we will use for our projects and we are very tempted by Laravel.

The framework looks very well built and the documentation very well structured. However we are wondering if the framework is mature enough to use in a production environment.

We are an advertising agency most of our mandates are fairly short lived. We sometimes run projects over severals years and it's specifically for those cases that we want to make sure we take the right decision. We don't want to end up supporting a project living on a framework that was just hype.

Does anyone have extensive experience with Laravel or FuelPHP used for bigger scale projects? We are often working on tight deadlines and we want to get feedback from people that have released several projects on one or another. Any issues? Recommendations on one or the other?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is probably going to get closed, as being `primarily opinion based`. I would suggest doing some research on the two frameworks. Theres a lot to think about, and I personally wouldn't jump so quickly towards Laravel. Personally, I'd use Symfony2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same question as "which fruit is better?" :-)

If you are looking for a well tested framework, than you should choose aura php or cake php. At aura you could only take, what you. You don´t need to take the whole Framework.

Zend Framework 1 was good, but Zend Framework 2 is just confused. So I would rather not choose Zend!

PS: node.js with typescript is also good and got many common function, which PHP doesn´t have.